# Auth0 Authentication | Combined SAML and Username-Password-Authentication Connections

Tags: auth0

Has anyone combined SAML and Database connection in one login widget .

i.e: I want two options to login via SAML (may be a button ) as well as with User Name and Password to login with single email address.

But with Lock JS , An internal user to LDAP/SAML can login via SAML only (if both connections are allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally I've been pondering the same question today myself. On the surface the only way I've come up with to address this issue seems to be by steering Lock on initialisation using allowedConnections parameter. Docs here

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#allowedconnections-array-

Does mean you need a mechanism for the user deciding (or steering via some other means) which connection you're trying to initialise Lock with.

Seems a bit strange given you can happily show multiple social connections alongside each other.

The other way if you have the luxury of being able to steer a user to a certain identity provider via their email address is to use home realm discovery on the SAML connection by entering an email domain. This does not work for my use case where my user base is not corporate in nature and so I cannot glean which identity provider to steer them towards based off their email domain. Good luck and if you find a better way I'd be very interested to hear ;)

Comment: Yeah , strange behavior for SAML Users. I had also decided to initialize lock with the connection once we know which connection to use for the user SAML/UserName-Password-Authentication by using the allowedConnections parameter. Thanks :)